# JSON formatting a String in android

Tags: java, android, json, server, formatting

I am trying to send in locations to a server. I'm supposed to send in these values to the server.

Send to server

```
{ “type”:”location”,
”id”:”ID”,
”longitude”:”LONGITUDE”,
“latitude”:”LATITUDE” }
```

My string I'm trying to send in

```
String sendPos = "{\"type\":\"location\",\"id\":\"" +getGrpID() + "\",\"longitude\":\"" + longitude + "\",\"latitude\":\"" + latitude + "}";
```

I'm supposed to get back same message as I sent in, but I don't get the correct latitude and longitute, instead I get NaN.

Comment: NaN means Not a Number, it may not be well formatted, maybe is a String and you are not parsing it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manually building up JSON strings.
Just use what the framework gives you to build up the JSON:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    jObj.put("type", "location");
    jObj.put("id", getGrpID());
    jObj.put("longitude", longitude);
    jObj.put("latitude", latitude);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String sendPos = jObj.toString();
```

Comment: This still gives me NaN as a result from the server

Comment: What does `getGrpID()` return?  Also, what are the types for `longitude` and  `latitude`?   What is the  value of `sendPos` before you send it?

Comment: getGrpID() is correct, longitude and latitude I have hardcoded just to check if it actually registers (it doesnt). sendPos value is `{"type":"location","id":"groupname,heye,1495481010186","longitude":151.211,"latitude":-33.852}`

Comment: Maybe the server is expecting a number for the ID?  As you have it now, it's sending a string for the ID.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is short for "Not a Number". NaN indicates that the monitoring system is not receiving any numeric data.

1 - Are the coordenates really at the suitable format?

2 - These values are correctly at the server?

The coordinates must be "long" type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson to deserialize.

Step-1: Create a standard POJO class.

```
public class Data{
        private String type;
        private String id;
        private double longitude;
        private double latitude;

        public Data(String type, String id, double longitude, double latitude) {
            this.type = type;
            this.id = id;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }
    }
```

Step-2: Easily convert this to String by Gson.

```
Data data = new Data("location", getGrpID(), longitude, latitude);
String sendPos = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

**Note:** Latitude and Longitude are of double data type.